# How to solve for $z$: $|z|=z+\bar{z}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm not sure how to figure this out (how to solve for $z$):

> $$|z|=z+\bar{z}$$

What I did was,

Let $$z=a+bi $$
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=(a+bi)+(a-bi)$$
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=2a$$
$$a^2+b^2=4a^2$$

I'm not sure what to do from here to solve for $z$...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go on!

You get $$b^2=3a^2\implies b=\pm a\sqrt3$$ so the equation holds for all the complex numbers satisfying $$z=a\pm a\sqrt3i$$ due to conjugacy, with $a>0$ because $|z|$ must be non-negative.

Comment: Could also have $-a\sqrt{3}$, no?

Comment: Note that $a>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Another fun approach is the following:

Let $z=re^{i\theta}$.  Then $\Re(z)=r\cos(\theta)$.  Substituting this into the equation gives
$$
r=2r\cos(\theta).
$$
Therefore, either $r=0$ or $\cos(\theta)=\frac{1}{2}$.  Hence $\theta=\frac{\pi}{3}$ or $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{3}$.  Then,
$$
z=re^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}\quad\text{or}\quad z=re^{-\frac{i\pi}{3}}
$$
If you want to match more of the details, then use that
$$
z=re^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}=r\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+ir\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{r}{2}+\frac{ir\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$b^2+a^2=4a^2\to b^2=3a^2\to b=\pm a\sqrt3$$
Then filter that back in for $$z=a\pm i\cdot a\sqrt3 $$

Answer (score 1):

Just some geometrical motivation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$a^2+b^2=4a^2\implies b^2=3a^2 \implies b=\pm \sqrt 3 a $$

$$ z= a+bi = a\pm i\sqrt 3 a  = a( 1\pm i\sqrt 3 ) $$